# Alert controller description message are not multiline , it get truncated tail.?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm using the alert controller (`NSMutableAttributedString` for title and message) to display an alert, but my message gets truncated at it's not multiline.
So anyway to multiline the message or I may need to changes any property for that please suggest.
The message comes from a server that's why it isn't possible to add the `\n`.

Please post any solution. 
Thanks in advance!

I just make normal demo it works perfectly, but I don't know why it will be not working in my project code?

**Here is my code:**

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    let alrtTitleStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Title message which will from server")
    alrtTitleStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0) , range: NSRange(location: 0, length: alrtTitleStr.length))

    let alrtMessage = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Here is the message which comes from server and it should be display in muultiline.")
    alrtMessage.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value:  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:16.0) , range: NSRange(location: 0, length: alrtMessage.length))

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.setValue(alrtTitleStr, forKey: "attributedTitle")
    alertController.setValue(alrtMessage, forKey: "attributedMessage")

    let btnYes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { action in
       //next process
    })
    let btnNo = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: { action in
        //next process
    })

    alertController.addAction(btnYes)
    alertController.addAction(btnNo)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: FYI - `UIAlertController` has not public support for setting attributed title and message. That code could crash with any iOS update. Best to avoid such undocumented properties.

Comment: It works for me perfectly

Comment: @Sanjukta - it works for me also in the simple demo but in my project any property which will I set programmatically that to affect into that's I think so. 

Please correct me if I'm wrong.
So is there any properly which effect.

Comment: @rmaddy: then how to change the alert title message color and font size. having any alternative solution.

Comment: @Vishal_Wagh it's pretty simple to write your own view controller to use instead of the system `UIAlertController` - then you will have full control over the formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**
If you write this type of code in your project then it's affected to some default properties of the alert controller. To remove this type of extension alert controller have default properties of multiline in swift 4

```
override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    guard let text = self.text else { return super.intrinsicContentSize }

    var contentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
    var textWidth: CGFloat = frame.size.width
    var insetsHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

    if let insets = padding {
        textWidth -= insets.left + insets.right
        insetsHeight += insets.top + insets.bottom
    }

    let newSize = text.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: textWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                    options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                    attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: self.font], context: nil)

    contentSize.height = ceil(newSize.size.height) + insetsHeight

    return contentSize
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `Swift 4` you can use multi-line strings:

- https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-create-multi-line-string-literals

Example:

```
let longString = ""
```

When you write a string that spans multiple
lines make sure you start its content on a
line all of its own, and end it with three
quotes also on a line of their own.
Multi-line strings also let you write "quote marks"
freely inside your strings, which is great!
"""

So, your code would be:

```
let longTextMessage = ""
```

When you write a string that spans multiple
lines make sure you start its content on a
line all of its own, and end it with three
quotes also on a line of their own.
Multi-line strings also let you write "quote marks"
freely inside your strings, which is great!
"""

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message:longTextMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert) 

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: 
UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)  

alert.addAction(okAction)

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

LE: I used your code with a long text message like:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message:"Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text ",
                                  preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:
        UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)

alert.addAction(okAction)

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

let strAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)]
       let alrtTitleStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Title message which will from server", attributes: strAttributes)

```
    let strAttributesMs = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:16.0)]
    let alrtMessage = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Here is the message which comes from server and it should be display in muultiline. Here is the message which comes from server and it should be display in muultiline. Here is the message which comes from server and it should be display in muultiline. Here is the message which comes from server and it should be display in muultiline.", attributes: strAttributesMs)

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.setValue(alrtTitleStr, forKey: "attributedTitle")
    alertController.setValue(alrtMessage, forKey: "attributedMessage")

    let btnYes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { action in
        //next process
    })
    let btnNo = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: { action in
        //next process
    })

    alertController.addAction(btnYes)
    alertController.addAction(btnNo)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```